# How to append a separator string when using System.out::print to print String[]?

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to learn and get comfortable using lambdas, streams and method references - all the new-fangled Java 11 stuff.

I want to sort and print out the array of strings, keeping the null intact.
In the last line, how can I print the names with spaces?
(a general case would be printing each name with a message).
The current output is:

> nullGoyleMalfoyCrabbe

I want

> null Goyle Malfoy Crabbe

without a space after the last element.

```
ArrayList<String> enemies = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Malfoy", "Crabbe", "Goyle", null));
List<String> es = enemies.stream().map(object -> Objects.toString(object,null)).collect(Collectors.toList());
String[] as = es.toArray(String[]::new);
Arrays.sort(as, Comparator.nullsFirst((a,b) -> a.length() - b.length()));
Arrays.stream(as).forEach(System.out::print);
```

Comment: `Objects.toString(object,null)` is redundant for String objects. All it does is returning same string for strings, and null for null (not "null").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simple solution would be to add a whitespace after each list entry:

```
Arrays.stream(as).map(s -> s + " ").forEach(System.out::print);
```

But this will also add a whitespace at the end.

Since Java 8 there's `StringJoiner` which can be configured with a separator, prefix and suffix:

```
StringJoiner s = new StringJoiner("my separator", "my prefix", "my suffix");
s.add("str 1");
s.add("str 2");
System.out.print(s.toString());
```

There's also a `Collector` that can join `Stream`s (which uses `StringJoiner` under the hood):

```
String s = myStream.collect(Collectors.joining("my separator", "my prefix", "my suffix"));
System.out.print(s);
```

`StringJoiner` does only add the separator **between** the elements, not at the end. If you want to add something at the end with `StringJoiner` you must add a suffix.

Comment: for a large array of strings, the first way is best - but it adds the delimiter to the end.

Comment: Why should it be "best"? These are just different options. I'd use `StringJoiner` or `Collectors.joining`

Comment: Isn't is more memory efficient? not concatenating the entire array of strings into a new string, before printing it out

Comment: If that's what you're after, you maybe shouldn't use Java `:D` Or take a look at GraalVM native images. Btw: Using `str + " "` for every element on the `Stream` will generate a new `String` for every element. Do you think this is better? I don't think so. And in general: The JVM will optimize the hot paths of your code. It can become faster and more memory efficient. You should run a benchmark with for example "JMH" and look at the results. But be warned: Results can vary, depending on your operating system, the manufacturer of the JVM, and the JVM version.

Comment: ok, thank you. your method #3 worked well. I pick it since it uses streams which is what I am trying to get familiar with. 
 `System.out.println(Arrays.stream(as).collect(Collectors.joining("=", "", "")));` output is `null=Goyle=Malfoy=Crabbe`

Comment: @likejudo The `Collectors.joining` method is overloaded, you can also use it with a single argument: `Collectors.joining("=")`. The default for prefix and suffix is already an empty string `""`.

Answer (score 3):

All you need is a `join`:

```
System.out.print(String.join(" ", as));
```

Comment: wow, I never heard of this. so simple. But it does create one new concatenated string of the entire array. I would have to do this `System.out.println(String.join(" ", as));` Is there a way to just print each string just joined with a space?

Comment: @likejudo even if it does create a new string, that's just in the scope of the print statement in your code currently

Comment: isn't that less memory efficient? to concatenate the entire array of strings before printing it out.

Comment: "less memory efficient"?   Well, maybe if we're talking thousands of Strings.  Otherwise, don't worry about it.   It's **printing out**, which is inherently slower than computation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `method reference` like below:

```
Arrays.stream(as).forEach(enem -> System.out.print(enem + " "));
```

Comment: Instead of "method reference" you probably meant "lambda" expression.

Answer (score 1):

One of the nice thing about streams (IMHO) is the method chaining. I would try something like this, doing everything within the stream pipeline:

```
    String output = Stream.of("Malfoy", "Crabbe", "Goyle", null)
            .map(object -> Objects.toString(object,null))
            .sorted(Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    System.out.format("Result is \"%s\".%n", output);
```

Output is:

> ```
> Result is "null Goyle Malfoy Crabbe".
> ```

You notice that there is no space after Crabbe.

If you had an array already, you can pass it to either `Arrays.stream()` or `Stream.of()` to create the first stream.